# C# listening to keys and output the results

Tags: c#, .net

I've the following code to output Meow or Awo according to the key I press.

It is working but for some reason after the first iteration of do/while I need to press twice on either c and d in order to make it output anything. Any ideas of how I can do it in a different way?

```
using System;

namespace Program
{
    interface Animal
    {
        void animalSound();
    }

    class Dog : Animal
    {
        public void animalSound()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Awo Awo!");
        }
    }

    class Cat : Animal
    {
        public void animalSound()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Meow");
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] a)
        {
            Dog myDog = new Dog();
            Cat myCat = new Cat();
            Console.WriteLine("--------Press C to call the Cat--------");
            Console.WriteLine("--------Press D to call the Dog--------");
            Console.WriteLine("Press double ESC to close the program");

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting the do loop 1");
                ConsoleKeyInfo KeyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
                while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting the while loop 2");
                    if (KeyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.C)
                    {
                        myCat.animalSound();
                    } else if(KeyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.D) {
                        myDog.animalSound();
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Breaking the while loop 3");
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Continue the do loop 4");
                continue;
            } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of second `Console.ReadKey` somehow.

Comment: @Sinatr you mean the one inside the while condition?

Answer (score 1):

wants a second entry from

```
Console.ReadKey(true).Key
```

user in your loop condition

Try This:

```
Dog myDog = new Dog();
Cat myCat = new Cat();
Console.WriteLine("--------Press C to call the Cat--------");
Console.WriteLine("--------Press D to call the Dog--------");
Console.WriteLine("Press double ESC to close the program");
ConsoleKeyInfo KeyInfo;
int counter = 1;
do
{
    KeyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);

    Console.WriteLine("Starting the while loop " + counter);
    counter++;

    if (KeyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.C)
    {
        myCat.animalSound();
    }
    else if (KeyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.D)
    {
        myDog.animalSound();
    }
} while (KeyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my little problem by changing the code like that:
I removed the first do and last while and kept only one while() with the condition needed

```
       KeyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
            while (KeyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {

                animal = GwtAnimal(KeyInfo);


                if (KeyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.C)
                {
                    myCat.AnimalSound();
                }
                else if (KeyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.D)
                {
                    myDog.AnimalSound();
                }

                KeyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
```